# Is it possible to change android built in midi player pitch bend range?

Tags: android, audio, midi

Is there a midi message that can be sent to the android midi player to adjust the pitch bend range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pitch bend sensitivity message that you could try. It's a MIDI RPN so you could try googling that for more info.

```
# pitch bend sensitivity message
101 0
100 0
6 2   #range in semitones, 2 semitones is the default, 24 is the max.
38 0  #range in cents
```

Comment: I've looked it up, this should be what I need. Thank you!